# Athena table with multiple locations

Tags: hive, amazon-athena

My data are distributed over multiple directories and multiple tab-separated files within those directories. The general structure looks like this:

```
s3://bucket_name/directory/{year}{month}/{iso_2}/{year}{month}{day}_table.bcp.gz
```

where `{year}` is the 4-digit year, `{month}` is the 2-digit month, `{day}` is the 2-digit day and `{iso_2}` is the ISO2 country code.

How do I set this up as a table in Athena?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Athena uses Hive DDL, so you just need to run a normal Hive create statement:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table_name(
  col_1 string,
...
  col_n string)
PARTITIONED BY (
   year_month string,
   iso_2 string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://bucket_name/directory/';
```

Then register these directories as new partitions to the required table by running `MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name`. If this fails for some reason (which it sometimes does in Athena) you'll need to run all the add partition statements for your existing directories:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PARTITION 
     (year_month=201601,iso=US) LOCATION 's3://bucket_name/directory/201601/US/'; 
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PARTITION 
     (year_month=201602,iso=US) LOCATION 's3://bucket_name/directory/201602/US/';
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PARTITION 
     (year_month=201601,iso=GB) LOCATION 's3://bucket_name/directory/201601/GB/';
etc.
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the `ALTER`'s automatically? Like have Athena pick them up without having to specify them over and over again? From [here](http://blog.zhengdong.me/2012/02/22/hive-external-table-with-partitions/) it looks like we can't.