# Can I query a list of s3 path using athena?

Tags: amazon-athena

I have a list of s3 paths stored in a dynamodb table. For example, the user data on April 2nd was stored in s3://bucket/2022/04/02/user__2022-04-02.json.gz. I can query the dynamo DB table using Athena to get a list of s3 paths. How can I use that list of s3 paths to create a table in Athena and query that table?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to automatically regenerate a Glue table with the output of an Athena query using *only* Athena, that is in the realm of stored procedures and you're [out of luck](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/other-notable-limitations.html#:%7E:text=Stored%20procedures%20are%20not%20supported).

However, you can certainly use the result of an Athena query with some client that can process the result to [add partitions to a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41812878/athena-table-with-multiple-locations). For example, using powershell:

```
$result = Get-ATHQueryResult "<some-guid>"
$partitions = $result.Rows.Data.VarCharValue 
  | Select-Object -Skip 1  # Skips the header
  | ForEach-Object { 
    "alter table <your-table> add partition (<partition_key>=<some_value>) location '$_';" 
  }
```

This presumes that you have set up a structure for the table and that the data represented in `s3://bucket/2022/...` shares a similar structure. You can then use the same client to issue the resulting commands to Athena so the partitions are added.